# pbkdf2_hmac_sha1 with empty salt to set aes key

Tags: ruby, encryption, cryptography

I am encrypting several text in aes-256-cbc. I am generating the key using pbkdf2_hmac_sha1 using an empty salt. So the key does not vary between encryptions, although the iv is set to random_iv each time.

I am doing this for a library, basically here is my most recent push:

https://github.com/danpal/encryptor/commit/820da4c00f4caa4d448750bc7afea4c3b43af53b

as you can see the salt is empty but I do over 1000 rounds, and I also always set a random :iv
(options[:iv] comes from cipher.random_iv)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no actual question in your question, but I infer that it is: "am I doing it right ?"

And the answer is: no. You **MUST** use a random salt.

The point of the salt is to prevent an attacker from optimizing things by using parallelism, i.e. attacking several instances of your system (which use distinct passwords). Such parallelism can be a password-guessing attack and comparing with several encrypted messages; or maybe using precomputed tables (e.g. the much-hyped [rainbow tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table)). That's the same thing (space-wise or time-wise parallelism, that's not a big deal). A random salt thwarts parallelism.

Now that's a random salt *per password*. If you reuse the same password you can also reuse the same salt, which will then yield the same key; that's OK if the key is used for encryption with a new properly random IV for each *message*. But if someone else wants to use your software with a password of his own, he *must* have his own salt as well. Also, mind that this must be a *random* salt, **not** a "salt derived from the password with a hash function" (if you do not see why, then think again about what a precomputed table is about).

Comment: Thanks I reverted the commit :). https://github.com/danpal/encryptor/commit/a7cdfff0275414c303e0f5268555113e025dd635

Comment: Ping @Thomas: Sorry for the unrelated comment, but since you seem to have the top answer score for [tag:sha1], would you mind suggesting [tag:sha-1] as a synonym for it? I don't have enough answer score for that tag here on SO to do it myself.

Comment: Actually, would mind doing it for [tag:sha512] and [tag:sha-512] too?